# HTML Input field force numbers

Tags: mobile, user-input, wml

Is it possible to create an input field that sets the default input character set to numbers on a **mobile phone** (so the **NUMERICAL KEYBOARD POPS UP**)?
For example to make it easier type in a telephone number into a HTML form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to limit entry on a "mobile phone"
The mobile phone form entry uses

```
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml">
```

input here can be limited using format="*N"

Answer (score 36):

To make inputing numbers easier, use `<input type="number">`. To make entering phone numbers easier, use `<input type="tel">`. Not all phone will support them, but the iPhone at least will give you a numeric keypad by default instead of the normal keyboard. See [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html) and [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#type-number) for more information.

Comment: Watch out the limitations in entering periods and commas in such input fields: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35315157/1066234

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<input type='tel'>`.  This is a new HTML5 feature.  Older browsers will simply default to a text input field.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use either `type="tel"` or `type="numbers"`.

The difference is that one tries to bring up your phone dial keyboard and other simply switches to the numbers input of your mobile keyboard.

Comment: Thought that would work here: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/hbHsk however still stuck

Answer (score 1):

Please see my project of the cross-browser filter of value of the text input element on your web page using JavaScript language: [Input Key Filter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) . Code example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Phone number</h1>
 Please type a phone number in the +**(***)***-**-** format. Example: +1(23)456-78-90
 <br/>
 <input id="PhoneNumber" value="+()--">
 <script>
  function getArrayPhoneNumber(value){
   if (typeof value == 'undefined')
    value = document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value;
   return value.match(/^(\+?\d*)\((\d*)\)(\d*)-?(\d*)-?(\d*)$/);
  }
  
  function getPhoneNumber(){
   var arrayPhoneNumber = getArrayPhoneNumber();
   if(!arrayPhoneNumber)
    return "";
    
   var phoneNumber = arrayPhoneNumber[1] + arrayPhoneNumber[2] + arrayPhoneNumber[3] + arrayPhoneNumber[4] + arrayPhoneNumber[5];
   return phoneNumber;
  }
  
  inputKeyFilter.Create("PhoneNumber", function(event){//onChange event
    inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
    
    var arrayPhoneNumber = getArrayPhoneNumber();
    if(!arrayPhoneNumber || (arrayPhoneNumber.length != 6)){
     document.getElementById("NewPhoneNumber").innerHTML = "Incorrect format of the phone number";
     return;
    }
    
    var elementNewPhoneNumber = document.getElementById("NewPhoneNumber");
    var phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();
    if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(phoneNumber, this)){
     elementNewPhoneNumber.innerHTML = "";
     return;
    }
    elementNewPhoneNumber.innerHTML = phoneNumber;
   }
   , function(elementInput, value){//customFilter
    var arrayPhoneNumber = getArrayPhoneNumber(value);
    if(arrayPhoneNumber == null){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Недопустимый формат телефонного номера. Например: +1(234)56-78-90"
       : "Incorrect format of the phone number. Example: +1(234)56-78-90"
      , elementInput);
     if(elementInput.value == "")
      elementInput.value = elementInput.defaultValue;
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
   
   //onblur event. Use this function if you want set focus to the input element again if input value is NaN. (empty or invalid)
   , function(event){ inputKeyFilter.isNaN(parseInt(getPhoneNumber()), this); }
  );
 </script>
  New phone number: <span id="NewPhoneNumber"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page ["Custom filter:" example of the input key filter](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5hS0tFSGjBZfkhKS1VobnFDTkJKR0tVamxadmlvTmItQ2pxVWR0WDZPdHZxM2hzS1J3ejQ/InputKeyFilter/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with Javascript. This will only allow numbers from the numpad/numbers on top of the keypad, and formatters (shift/backspace/etc). You may also consider adding a `setTimeout()`, with a couple seconds timeout, for the `onchange` event to check in case someone pastes non numbers into the field as well as server side validation.

### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/vce9s/

Answer (score 0):

for my testing of "you can use either `type="tel"` or `type="numbers"`."
on iPhone `type="tel"` brings up the numbers only keypad (like phone) and `type="numbers"` brings up the numeric keypad switched to numbers and symbols, so both work, just depends on your application. For me I only need numbers so I used `type="tel"` for ease of use and it worked great!