# Setting lang attribute wont make change in input

Tags: html, multilingual, lang

In HTML5, we can mention lang of input.

Currently I have one input type=number field. If browser language is set to German then its allowing ',' (comma) but if browser language is set to English then it wont allow comma.

So I added lang attribute for html tag only, but its not allowing comma.

I have created [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruviyonaji/edit?html,output) for same.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de-AT' xml:lang="de-AT">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="number">
</body>
</html>
```

What is best way to set language as German (de-AT) for input ?

Answer (score 1):

Comma should be allowed in firefox, but for chrome it's a bit tricky, you need to use `<type=text>` and validate if the input is a number or not manually using javascript. This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315157/html5-input-box-with-type-number-does-not-accept-comma-in-chrome-browser), see it for details.