# HTML number field toLocalString not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML number field. This field value assigned throw following error

```
The specified value "101,5" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

I need a value to convert to `french` format (de-DE).
My try is

```js
var dispersePercentageInput = $('.disperse-percentage');
var percentage = 101.5
dispersePercentageInput.val(Number(percentage).toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="etude_disbursement_rate" value="100.00" class="disperse-percentage required" step="0.01" data-prefix="-" required="" id="id_etude_disbursement_rate" title="S'il vous plaît remplissez cet champ">
```

I expect value is `101,5` but it shows `The specified value "101,5" is not a valid number.`

My input field is

```
<input type="number" name="etude_disbursement_rate" value="100.00" class="disperse-percentage required" step="0.01" data-prefix="-" required="" id="id_etude_disbursement_rate" title="S'il vous plaît remplissez cet champ">
```

User input in en-US format

Comment: Working fine for me, can you reproduce in snippet?

Comment: I am using `jQuery v1.11.2` version. Is this produce error?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with jquery version.

Comment: What does your actual input HTML look like? Is it the same as what was added by Mamun?

Comment: I can see the desired value in the console. But it not shows in input field.

Comment: I don't think `number` inputs currently accept commas. Try entering a comma into the input in the snippet above. Your only option might be to use a `text` type input.

Comment: I convert input field to text. ANd it's working fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input box with type="number" does not accept comma in Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315157/html5-input-box-with-type-number-does-not-accept-comma-in-chrome-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});
console.log("Output: "+formatter.format(sum));
```

This working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Please use "autoNumeric.min.js"

```
<script src="~/Scripts/autoNumeric/autoNumeric.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

add input tag in HTML file :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberint" data-a-dec="," data-a-sep="." data-a-sign="">
```

Script code :

```
<script type="text/text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#numberint').autoNumeric('init');   
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, of course. `input:type=number` is not a good choice, it can just accept common format, but your format is very infrequent.

and `number` type has some other defects, such as

1. not behave all the same in different browsers
2. allows multiple `.`
3. allows letter `e`

I recommend use just `text` type instead, and check format by RegExp or other way